# When/where to place different types of tracking markers?

Tags: tracking

More of a general question that I never seem to find an answer to:

When and where are the correct decisions to place different types of tracking markers? When do I know to place Perspective, location, location+rotation, loc+rot+scale, or Affine? I know I only need a minimum of 8 trackers to solve for camera etc but how many of each tracker is best? Do you just use one, two types of trackers or all of them? And if you were to just use one type of tracker, which would it be?

I have a general understanding of what each tracker does and have tracked some videos by now, but seem to get differing quality of results and want to know how to make it more consistent. Thank you to anyone who answers this.